# Selective API documentation using Swagger/Open API

Tags: c#, swagger, documentation

I have a C# project that uses various API calls and odata to work with database elements.

Using swagger to automatically generate API documentation for the entire project doesn't really work in this case because the output file becomes too massive.

I am trying to find out if its possible to use separate JSON files to create documentation for selected calls using swagger? Or any other utility that can help with this.

Comment: I might have missed the point where you are exactly but if you are talking about separating you own Asp.Net API into multiple parts to get them in a more handy size Swashbuckle (and presumably other generator) can do that. The ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute  allows grouping see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents

Comment: I am very new to this and most likely didn't explain it right. Main issue right now is that we use odata to work with purchase orders, sales orders and etc. Swagger tries to create API documentation for every single entry and it becomes too big. I was wondering if its possible to manualy make a json of a REST API call and process it in swagger? Or does it make no sense to do it individually?